# Ordering a pagination by a third relationship (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

My tables look like this:

**Images**

Id

User_id

Path

**Users**

Id

Name

Password

**Posts**

Id

Content

User_id

I wish to paginate all posts. I would like the posts whose related user has an image to go first, then the rest. Currently, I have this, but it is not quite what I am looking for:

```
$posts = Post::where('subject_id', '=', $subject->id)
        ->approved()
        ->select(['*', DB::raw('(SELECT count(images.id) FROM images INNER JOIN users ON images.user_id = users.id WHERE posts.user_id = users.id) as count_images')])
        ->orderBy('count_images', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(18);
```

Comment: What is the issue with your current results? I think you might want to try an outer join.

Comment: Please describe the issue